# How do I suppress warnings for dependencies in sourcecode generators?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, csproj, .net-standard-2.0

TL:DR; How do I disable warnings that come through a `IncludeAssets="Build"` dependency?

I've written a sourcecode generator that includes an external dependency ([Scriban](https://github.com/scriban/scriban)). Including dependencies is a bit tricky and as far as I understand you have to actually include the sourcecode of the dependency rather than the dll.

Anyway. Management enforces a strict `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` policy lately and the dependency rises some warnings. I'm not allowed to use `<NoWarn>` or `<WarningsNotAsErrors>`.

So what can I do, to disable warnings for this depdency?

Thanks

Comment: You have <WarningsNotAsErrors>error_codesu</WarningsNotAsErrors> but not sure which is the the code of that warning. And If you suppress that  - will it effect other warning in future. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#nowarn